# Primary ideals are primal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity.

- Recall an ideal $I \subseteq R$ is *primary* if $ab \in I$ implies $a \in I$ or $b^n \in I$ for some $n$.
- $I$ is *primal* if its *adjoint* $I^{\not\perp}\ := \{ a \in R: \exists\, b \notin I \text{ such that } ab \in I \}$ is an ideal.

I am struggling to prove that every primary ideal is primal. It is easily shown that the adjoint of *any* ideal contains $0$, is closed under negation and absorbent under multiplication. So, somehow I need to use the primary-ness of $I$ to show $I^{\not\perp}\ $ is closed under addition, but I can't see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_1,a_2\in I^{\not\perp}$. Then there are some $b_1,b_2\notin I$ such that $a_1b_1, a_2b_2\in I$. Since $I$ is primary it follows that we must have $a_1,a_2\in\sqrt{I}$, and so $c:=a_1+a_2\in\sqrt{I}$ as well. Take the minimal $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $c^n\in I$. Then $c\cdot c^{n-1}=c^n\in I$, where $c^{n-1}\notin I$. Hence $c\in I^{\not\perp}$.

Comment: Nice. It seems you're essentially proving that $I^{\not\perp} = \sqrt{I}$, which is probably the easiest way to do it.